# I want to filter html table data in react. but I am not able to filter all data in React.js (or only js)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table, datatable

I want to filtering in html table all data.

this is my code

```js
  const handleSearch = e => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    const input = document.getElementById("search-input");
    const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    const table = document.getElementById("patients");
    const tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    let td, i;

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > - 1) {
          tr[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This code results td[0] result filtering.
I want to other td[i] data filtering 
(for example, I input text td[1] or td[2] value, I will see filtering td[1] data or td[2] data.
but, I don't know how to filtering. plz help me.

Comment: Do you have static table inside the jsx component? I would rather dynamically render all of the table with filtered results before that. Can you share your component code?

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz 
sorry, Table data is secret. and thanks to answer. and my problem was cracked!